# com.auth0.IdentityVerificationException: An error occurred while exchanging the Authorization Code for Auth0 Tokens

Tags: auth0

I am trying to implement auth0 in a very basic spring-boot-application based on maven. This is the error that I get:

> com.auth0.IdentityVerificationException: An error occurred while exchanging the Authorization Code for Auth0 Tokens

When running the original tutorial-project everything works fine. The error occurs only in my custom application. Basically I copied all the files from the tutorial-project into my application. Nevertheless I run into this error...

further down the exception I see a

> com.auth0.exception.APIException: Request failed with status code 401: Unauthorized

Answer (score 2):

**Solved it:**

The client-secret was wrong. Actually there is a space at the end of my client-secret, which I accidentally removed. Wow.